# How to convert gzip.GzipFile to dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, text, gzip

I have a `gz` format file. The file is very big and the first line is as follow:

```
 {"originaltitle":"Leasing Specialist - WPM Real Estate Management","workexperiences":[{"company":"Home Properties","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"","startdate":null,"enddate":null},"description":"Responsibilities: Inspect tour routes, models and show apartments daily to ensure cleanliness. Greeting prospective residents; determining the needs and preferences of the prospect and professionally present specific apartments while providing information regarding features and benefits. Answering incoming calls in a cheerful and professional manner. Handle each call accordingly whether it is a prospect call or an irate resident that just moved in. Develop and maintain Resident relations through the courtesy of on-site personnel, promptness of maintenance calls, and knowledge of community policies. Learn to develop professional sales and closing techniques. Accompany prospects to model apartments and discusses size and layout of rooms, available facilities, such as swimming pool and saunas, location of shopping centers, services available, and terms of lease. Demonstrate thorough knowledge and use of lead tracking system. Make follow-up calls to prospective Residents who did not fill out an application. Compile and update listings of available rental units.","location":"Baltimore, MD","normalizedtitle":"leasing specialist","title":"Leasing Specialist"},{"company":"WPM Real Estate Management","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"1 year, 3 months","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"July 2017 to October 2018","startdate":{"displaydate":"July 2017","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}},"enddate":{"displaydate":"October 2018","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}}},"description":"Responsibilities:  Inspect tour routes, models and show apartments daily to ensure cleanliness. Greeting prospective residents; determining the needs and preferences of the prospect and professionally present specific apartments while providing information regarding features and benefits. Answering incoming calls in a cheerful and professional manner. Handle each call accordingly whether it is a prospect call or an irate resident that just moved in. Develop and maintain Resident relations through the courtesy of on-site personnel, promptness of maintenance calls, and knowledge of community policies. Learn to develop professional sales and closing techniques. Accompany prospects to model apartments and discusses size and layout of rooms, available facilities, such as swimming pool and saunas, location of shopping centers, services available, and terms of lease. Demonstrate thorough knowledge and use of lead tracking system. Make follow-up calls to prospective Residents who did not fill out an application. Compile and update listings of available rental units.","location":"Baltimore, MD","normalizedtitle":"leasing specialist","title":"Leasing Specialist"},{"company":"Westminster Management","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"1 year","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"June 2016 to June 2017","startdate":{"displaydate":"June 2016","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}},"enddate":{"displaydate":"June 2017","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}}},"description":"Responsibilities:  Tour vacant units and model with future prospects.Process applications. Answer emails and incoming phone calls. Prepare lease agreement for signing. Collect all monies that is due on dateof move-in. Enter resident repair orders for resident. Walk vacant units to ensure that the unit is ready for show. Complete residency and employment verifications. Income qualify all applicants.","location":"Baltimore, MD","normalizedtitle":"leasing consultant","title":"Leasing Consultant"},{"company":"MARYLAND MANAGEMENT COMPANY","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"1 year, 1 month","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"April 2015 to May 2016","startdate":{"displaydate":"April 2015","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}},"enddate":{"displaydate":"May 2016","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}}},"description":"Responsibilities:  Lease apartments, sign lease agreements, complete residence maintenance repairrequest, answer phones, customer service, processed prospects applications, opened and closedinventory, responded to Level One emails Accomplishments: I was able to successfully finish FairHousing requirements. The first month I was able to properly and accurately process a application and move-in documents. Skills Used: The skills I used while at Americana were strong team work, strongcommunication, interpersonal, and leadership.","location":"Glen Burnie, MD","normalizedtitle":"leasing agent","title":"Leasing Agent"},{"company":"Amazon.com","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"1 year, 5 months","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"September 2014 to February 2016","startdate":{"displaydate":"September 2014","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}},"enddate":{"displaydate":"February 2016","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}}},"description":"Responsibilities: I assure customers are receiving the correct merchandise in a timely fashion.And evaluate inventoryAccomplishments:I exceeded Amazon expectations of receiving 2800 items per hour, which allowed me to train otherassociates, building confidence and skills.Skills Used:The skills i used while performing my task were strong leadership, strong communications, and beingdetailed orientated.","location":"Baltimore, MD","normalizedtitle":"customer service representative","title":"Customer Service Representative"},{"company":"Carmax Superstore","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"1 year, 2 months","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"February 2014 to April 2015","startdate":{"displaydate":"February 2014","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}},"enddate":{"displaydate":"April 2015","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}}},"description":"Responsibilities:Greet customersSearch for the right vehicle that best suits the customers needs and wantsSubmit financial applicationsAssist customer with the purchasing process and document signingEnter customers information for appraisal offerAssist customer with purchasing Car Max extended warrantiesConducted follow- up on a daily, weekly, and monthy basisAccomplishments:I was acknowledged by the district for having 100% in Car Max extended warranties. Also I wasacknowledged by the district for having one of the highest Voice Of Customer survey scores. I passedthe 6 week training, obtaining my sales licenseSkills Used:I demonstrate strong communication, interpersonal and listening skills. I also have strongorganizational skills.","location":"Nottingham, MD","normalizedtitle":"sales consultant","title":"Certified Sales Consultant"},{"company":"rue21","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"1 year, 8 months","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"June 2011 to February 2013","startdate":{"displaydate":"June 2011","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}},"enddate":{"displaydate":"February 2013","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}}},"description":"Responsibilities: Managed profit goals on a daily basisCustomer ServiceReceived Incoming shipmentDelivered daily bank depsoitsMaintained store appearanceOverlooked sales associates performanceCreated daily goals for each sales associateAccomplishments:The impact that I was able to have during my time at Rue21, I was able to build a strong team of individuals who were scored top in the region for Customer Service.Skills Used:I demonstrated strong leadership and verbal communication.","location":"Dundalk, MD","normalizedtitle":"assistant store manager","title":"Assistant Store Manager"},{"company":"Shaws Jewelers","country":"US","customizeddaterange":"1 year, 5 months","daterange":{"displaydaterange":"November 2009 to April 2011","startdate":{"displaydate":"November 2009","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}},"enddate":{"displaydate":"April 2011","granularity":"MONTH","isodate":{"date":null}}},"description":"Responsibilities: Customer serviceGeneral office( typing, faxing, )Made outgoing calls to valued customersCleaned and maintained show cases and lunch roomPrepared jewlery repair tickets for outgoing shipmentAccomplishments:During my time at Shaws Jewelers I was able to demonstrate excellent customer service.Also I wasable to achieve personal profit goals and credit application goals on a daily basis. I was acknowledged and rewarded by my DM for excellent team participation and over achieving the 6 standards on a dailybasis.Skills Used:I demonstrated strong verbal and listening skills. Also I have excellent interpersonal skills.","location":"Dundalk, MD","normalizedtitle":"sales associate","title":"Sales Associate"}],"skillslist":[{"monthsofexperience":0,"text":"yardi"},{"monthsofexperience":0,"text":"marketing"},{"monthsofexperience":0,"text":"outlook"},{"monthsofexperience":0,"text":"receptionist"},{"monthsofexperience":0,"text":"management"}],"url":"/r/Lashannon-Felton/1062d3b8cbb13886","additionalinfo":""}\n'
```

I am not familiar with `gzip.GzipFile` format.

Is there a way to make it a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make use of the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module and the [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) module in Python, both of which are part of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

> The gzip module provides the GzipFile class, as well as the open(),
> compress() and decompress() convenience functions. The GzipFile class
> reads and writes gzip-format files, automatically compressing or
> decompressing the data so that it looks like an ordinary file object.

To read the compressed file, you can call [`gzip.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open).

Opening the file with the default `rb` mode, will return a [`gzip.GzipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) object, from which you can obtain a [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) by calling [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read).

Then, using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), you can convert the raw data into a usable Python object -- a dictionary.

The snippet below is a simple demonstration of this in action:

```
import gzip
import json

with gzip.open('gzipped_file.json.gz', 'rb') as f:
    raw_json = f.read()
    data = json.loads(raw_json)

    print(type(data))
    # Prints <class 'dict'>

    print(data)
    # Prints {'originaltitle': 'Leasing Specialist - WPM Real Estate Management', 'workexperience ...

    print(data['workexperiences'][0]['company'])
    # Prints Home Properties
```